# Constructor and methods not working when in a test class java

Tags: java

I am working on a program that simulates a bug moving along a horizontal line, My code works correctly when I test it in it's own class but when I tried testing my constructors and methods in a test class I recieved an error saying, "cannot find symbol" on my constructor Bug. I'm still new to java so I'm not sure we're my mistake is.
Edit.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package bugtester;
/**
 *
 * @author Luke
 */
public class BugTester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Bug juneBug = new Bug(0);
      juneBug.move();
      juneBug.turn();
      juneBug.move();
      System.out.println(juneBug.getposition());
    }

}

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package bug;

/**
 *
 * @author Luke
 */
public class Bug {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    public int position;
    public int turner = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Bug juneBug = new Bug(0);
      juneBug.move();
      juneBug.turn();
      juneBug.move();
      juneBug.move();
      System.out.println(juneBug.getposition());

    }
    public Bug(int initialPosition){
        position = initialPosition;
        turner = 1;

    }
    public void turn(){

        turner = turner + 1;
    }
    public void move(){
        if (turner % 2 == 0){
             position = position - 1;
        }else{
             position = position + 1;
    }

    }
    public int getposition(){
        return position;
}
}
```

Comment: have you added the `import` for your class?

Comment: Have you done any research? `cannot find symbol` is an extremely common error when you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I don't think so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Apparently your code has a bug :) Joking aside, if you want a proper answer, we need to see the code, some information about the setup and the error being thrown.

Comment: At a minimum, we need to see the *entire* `BugTester` class and the package declaration for `Bug`.

Comment: are all your classes in a same package?

Comment: Post your ***complete*** error message. For all we know, your Bug constructor may not accept an int parameter. And show your Bug class.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting your classes in completely separate packages and not `import`ing `Bug` into `BugTester`. Put both classes in `package bug`.

Comment: I don't understand how to do that, how do I do that?

Comment: @user3806295 You put `BugTester` in `bug` the same way you did `Bug`. Use your IDE or manually edit and move `BugTester.java`.